# iFrame with dynamic binding is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular, I am trying to embed the PowerBi reports dynamically change the src of the iFrame like below

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
   Power BI Reports
  </h1>
  </div>
<select (onclick) = "selectedOption($event)">
    <option> Select </option>
  <option value="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=&groupId=&autoAuth=true&ctid="> Colony Productivity</option>
</select>

<iframe width="1140" height="541.25" ng-if="safeUrl" src="safeUrl" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the component.ts is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'PowerBIIntegration';
selectedValue: string = ''; 
safeUrl: SafeHtml ='';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}
  selectedOption( event : any){
    this.selectedValue = event.target.value;
   this.safeUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.selectedValue);
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  }
}
```

When I try to call http://localhost:4200. The page keeps loading with the error

`Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.`

`core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'safeUrl'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'safeUrl'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)

[image]

Comment: try to use [src] instead of src

Comment: You're using angularJS html syntax in angular.
change `(onclick)` to `(click)` and `ng-if` to `*ngIf`.

Comment: in my case i had to change the data target of  the target <a> o button with button [attr.data-target]="name-modal+data['id']"   and the modal class with  [class]="'modal fade modal-name'+data['id']"

Answer (score 1):

You are doing lots of mistakes. Like for bindings events in Angular `on` prefix should be avoided and you are using that on `select` element. Instead of `click` use `change` event. Other mistakes you are doing with `DomSanitizer` service. As we are using the `resource` url and then we should use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` instead of `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. You are also doing mistakes using `bindings` (look closely `*ngIf`, `[src]`) in Angular. I had done some correction in your code and below are the updated code.

component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
   Power BI Reports
  </h1>
  </div>
<select (change)="selectedOption($event)">
    <option> Select </option>
  <option value="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=&groupId=&autoAuth=true&ctid="> Colony Productivity</option>
</select>

<iframe width="1140" height="541.25" *ngIf="safeUrl" [src]="safeUrl" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'PowerBIIntegration';
  selectedValue: string = ''; 
  safeUrl: SafeHtml ='';

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  selectedOption( event : any){
    this.selectedValue = event.target.value;
    this.safeUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.selectedValue);
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the mistakes, I tried using *ng-if. But I was getting `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'iframe'. ("
</select>
<iframe width="1140" height="541.25" [ERROR ->]*ng-if="safeUrl" [src]="safeUrl" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
<router-outlet></ro"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@11:37
Property binding ng-if not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". `

Comment: It is *ngIf not *ng-if. Please try using the shared code.

Answer (score 0):

Solve this using

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

```
<iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(unsafeURL)">
```